# AUTO_INCREMENT in composite key

Tags: mysql, database-design, auto-increment, composite-key

I have table as below

**personalInfo**

```
CREATE TABLE personalInfo(userid BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
```

**patentInfo**

```
CREATE TABLE patentInfo 
(
 userid BIGINT,
 patentId BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
 FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES personalInfo(userid), 
 PRIMARY KEY (userid,patentId)
)
```

While creating table `patentInfo`, I am getting error as

```
Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key.
```

What I want to do is add patent for Users. So I was trying to use `patentId` as `AUTO_INCREMENT` and keep compiste primary key as combination of `patentId` & `userid`.

Any idea how can I get this done?

### Update 1:

My AIM is, I don't want to insert `patentId` in mysql query. mysql itself will create next number.

Comment: What is the difference between user and patient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `patentId` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then the it should be the primary key.

Comment: `patentInfo` table with the PK `patentId` sounds right, why do you want to composite primary key when only one is enough?

Comment: I got what you meant to say. Kept `patentId` as PK. Still just curious, is there any way to create composite key like that??

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a `Person` instead `user` -- suppose you have a clinic...

- `Patient` is a `Person`
- `Doctor` is a `Person`
- `Doctor` may become (is a) a `Patient` too.

[image]

- Keep all common personal information in `Person`
- Only patient-specific columns in `Patient`
- Only doctor specific in `Doctor`
- The subtype is inclusive, so discriminator has {B= both}
- Note how primary key propagates into sub-type tables.

---

To summarize, for your specific example, both tables should have `UserID` as the primary key. In the second table it is also a foreign key too.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have to auto-increment values in one table. so You have to manally insert the userid in patentinfo table at code level by using last_insert_id() or something similar to that instead of doing this at db-level

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can have a composite primary key with one auto_increment column provided the auto_increment column is the first clause to the primary key.

The following works on my machine

```
CREATE TABLE patentInfo 
(
  userid BIGINT,
  patentId BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (patentId, userid)
)
```

Where as

```
PRIMARY KEY (userid, patentId)
```

gives the error you are seeing.

Tested on MariaDB 10.0 YMMV